# Shift images to the right in TensorFlow

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I've made a learning on Tensorflow (MNIST) and I've saved the weights in a .ckpt.
Now I want to test my neural network on this weights, with the same images translated of a few pixels to the right and bottom.
The loading weigths works well, but when I print an eval, Tensorflow display always the same results (0.9630 for the test), whatever the translation is about 1 or 14px.
Here is my code for the function which print the eval :

```
def eval_translation(sess, eval_correct, images_pl, labels_pl, dataset):
    print('Test Data Eval:')
    for i in range(28):
        true_count = 0  # Counts the number of correct predictions.
        steps_per_epoch = dataset.num_examples // FLAGS.batch_size
        nb_exemples = steps_per_epoch * FLAGS.batch_size
        for step in xrange(steps_per_epoch):
            images_feed, labels_feed = dataset.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
            feed_dict = {images_pl: translate_right(images_feed, i), labels_pl: labels_feed}
            true_count += sess.run(eval_correct, feed_dict=feed_dict)
        precision = true_count / nb_exemples
        print('Translation: %d  Num examples: %d  Num correct: %d  Precision @ 1: %0.04f' % (i, nb_exemples, true_count, precision))
```

This is the function which with I load the datas and which with I print the test results.
Here is my translation function :

```
def translate_right(images, dev):
    for i in range(len(images)):
        for j in range(len(images[i])):
            images[i][j] = np.roll(images[i][j], dev)
    return images
```

I call this function in place of the learning just after initialise all the variables :

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    # Generate placeholders for the images and labels.
    images_placeholder, labels_placeholder = placeholder_inputs(FLAGS.batch_size)

    # Build a Graph that computes predictions from the inference model.
    weights, logits = mnist.inference(images_placeholder, neurons)

    # Add to the Graph the Ops for loss calculation.
    loss = mnist.loss(logits, labels_placeholder)

    # Add to the Graph the Ops that calculate and apply gradients.
    train_op = mnist.training(loss, learning_rate)

    # Add the Op to compare the logits to the labels during evaluation.
    eval_correct = mnist.evaluation(logits, labels_placeholder)

    # Build the summary operation based on the TF collection of Summaries.
    summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()

    # Create a saver for writing training checkpoints.
    save = {}
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        save['weights' + str(i)] = weights[i]
    saver = tf.train.Saver(save)

    # Create a session for running Ops on the Graph.
    sess = tf.Session()
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)

    # load weights
    saver.restore(sess, restore_path)

    # Instantiate a SummaryWriter to output summaries and the Graph.
    summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(FLAGS.train_dir, sess.graph)

    temps_total = time.time()

    eval_translation(sess, eval_correct, images_placeholder, labels_placeholder, dataset.test)
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code, and why Tensorflow seems to ignore my images.
Can someone could help me please ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You function `translate_right` doesn't work, because `images[i, j]` is just one pixel (containing 1 value if you have greyscale images).

You should use the argument `axis` of `np.roll`:

```py
def translate_right(images, dev):
    return np.roll(images, dev, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you ! I thought that my translation worked (I've display the images and seen the translation), but with the axis arg it works well and Tensorflow print the corrects values !